# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException : getting a SEVERE: null

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm new in programming and I want to do some filter with the data that grouped by the rent date . but I get error

```
revenuebylocs bt_filterActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Rent_Date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2014-02-02' GROUP BY Rent_Date, a.Branch_ID' at line 1
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2618)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2568)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1557)
        at revenuebylocs.bt_filterActionPerformed(revenuebylocs.java:282)
        at revenuebylocs.access$200(revenuebylocs.java:27)
        at revenuebylocs$3.actionPerformed(revenuebylocs.java:179)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6267)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6032)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

and here's my code

```
private void bt_filterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
         try {
             String value1= ((JTextField)dt_rangeto.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
            String value2= ((JTextField)dt_rangefrom.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();

            String sql = " SELECT DISTINCT(Rent_Date) AS DATE, Branch_Name , SUM(Rent_Amount)"+
                        "FROM t_rent a INNER JOIN t_rent_detail b ON a.Rent_ID = "+
                           "b.Rent_ID INNER JOIN t_branch c ON a.Branch_ID=c.Branch_ID"+
                           "WHERE Rent_Date BETWEEN '"+value2+"' AND '"+value1+"' "+
                           "GROUP BY Rent_Date, a.Branch_ID ";

             Pst = koneksi.getKoneksi().prepareStatement(sql);
            rs=Pst.executeQuery(sql);
            tb_revenue.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Filtered");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(staff.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Data");
        }

    }
```

what did I do wrong ? I can show it if I input the value of the rent_date manually . I test it on mysqlog.
here's the string that I tried on mysqlog

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Rent_Date) AS DATE, Branch_Name , SUM(Rent_Amount) 
FROM t_rent a INNER JOIN t_rent_detail b ON a.Rent_ID = 
b.Rent_ID INNER JOIN t_branch c ON a.Branch_ID=c.Branch_ID 
WHERE Rent_Date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2014-02-02'
GROUP BY Rent_Date, a.Branch_ID
```

and it showing just fine. it won't work in java . do I need to add something ?

Oh and one more question. I want to show my table like this:

```
Date           S    Mrental
2014-01-01  10000   10000
2014-05-05  10000   10000
```

How can I do that? (S and M is the Branch_Name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add space before `WHERE` (and before `FROM` as well)

```
" WHERE Rent_Date BETWEEN '"+value2+"' AND '"+value1+"' "
```

Comment: ty . what about the table ?